# Jenkins --FATAL:hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: jenkins

I got the below exception in my Jenkins slave and I'm not able to launch the slave after this.

**FATAL:hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset**

Now when I tried launching the slave from master node I'm getting the below error.

**Checking if Java exists
ERROR: Failed to prepare Java
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException**

I read it in Jenkins forum that it requires Remote Connection Service to be running. But I'm not able to start it getting Error 193 :0xc1

Can you help in fixing this or do I need to delete the slave completely and recreate it?

Comment: How is the slave->master connection configured - does it use JNLP, SSH or DCOM?

Comment: Jenkins control this slave as a windows service.It uses DCOM

Comment: That means DCOM. At least on a multi-slave setup that I've been working on I had to make the windows slaves connect over JNLP due to problems with Jenkins' DCOM slave connection.